# Conceptual Graph - inspired database

Tags: database, semantics, semantic-web, knowledge-management, conceptual-model

I'm looking for the database using the [idea of conceptual graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conceptual_graph) proposed by [John F. Sowa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_F._Sowa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Web Ontology Language is pretty close to what you want. You can express all of that, including situations and propositions, although those are somewhat clunky because you would have to use named graphs.

Answer (score 0):

The Conceptual Graphs mentioned by John Sowa are mentioned as one form of the Common Logic ISO Standard. You might find something using that information.